# Use webpack-chain to do webpack configuration in vue.config.js, so how to use speed-measure-webpack-plugin plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

This is the configuration file of my vue-cli3

vue.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')
const SpeedMeasurePlugin = require("speed-measure-webpack-plugin");
const smp = new SpeedMeasurePlugin();

module.exports = {
  publicPath: './',
  lintOnSave: true, 
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.devServer
      .port(8089)
      .open(true)
      .disableHostCheck(true)

    config.when(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development', config => {

      config  
        .plugin('gzip')
        .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin, [{
          algorithm: 'gzip',  
          test: new RegExp('\\.(' + ['js', 'css'].join('|') + ')$'),
          threshold: 8192,
          minRatio: 0.8,
          cache: true
        }])
    })
  }
}
```

According to the configuration of speed-measure-webpack-plugin, all the plugins are wrapped, but if you use webpack-chain, can you not use this plugin?

Answer (score -1):

It's work for me. ref this comment

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6091#issuecomment-738536334