# Vuejs Webpack Compression Plugin not compressing

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I need help debugging Webpack's Compression Plugin.

**SUMMARY OF PROBLEM**

- Goal is to enable asset compression and reduce my app's bundle size. Using the Brotli algorithm as the default, and gzip as a fallback for unsupported browsers.
- I expected a ***content-encoding*** field within an asset's Response Headers. Instead, they're loaded without the field. I used the Chrome dev tools' network tab to confirm this. For context, see the following snippet:
  [image: example asset request]
- No errors show in my browser or IDE when running locally.

**WHAT I TRIED**

- Using different implementations for the compression plugin. See below list of approaches:

  1. (With Webpack Chain API)

```
config
 .plugin('brotliCompress')
     .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin, [{
       exclude: /.map$/,
       cache: true,
       algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
       test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
       threshold: 10240,
       minRatio: 0.8,
     }])
```

2. (With Webpack Chain API)

```
config
  .plugin('gzip')
      .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin, [{
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: new RegExp('\\.(' + ['js', 'css'].join('|') + ')$'),
        threshold: 8192, // Assets larger than 8192 bytes are not processed
        minRatio: 0.8, // Assets compressing worse that this ratio are not processed
      }])
```

3. (With Webpack Chain API)

```
config
  .plugin('CompressionPlugin')
      .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin)
```

4. (Using vue-cli-plugin: compression) This fails due to a ***Missing generator*** error when I use `vue invoke compression` in response to an IDE console message after I run `vue add compression` as an alternative to using Webpack Chain API for compression configuration.

```
  pluginOptions: {
    compression: {
      brotli: {
        filename: '[file].br[query]',
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        minRatio: 0.8,
      },
      gzip: {
        filename: '[file].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        minRatio: 0.8
      }
    }
  },
```

5. Lastly, I tried setting the threshold field to 0 as well as raising it larger than 10k bytes.

**POINTS OF SIGNIFICANCE**

- The above attempts didn't achieve the goal I stated in the first summary bullet and were used in place of the previous approaches tested.
- I prioritized my efforts with Webpack Chain API since it resulted in no errors when rebuilding and running the app.

**REFERENCED LINKS/DOCS**

- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/
- https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/tree/main
- https://neutrinojs.org/webpack-chain/#config-plugins-adding
- https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/500 (similar generator issue with another plugin)
- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/
- [Use webpack-chain to do webpack configuration in vue.config.js, so how to use speed-measure-webpack-plugin plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380714/use-webpack-chain-to-do-webpack-configuration-in-vue-config-js-so-how-to-use-sp) (not a valid answer, but referenced syntax nonetheless)
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6091#issuecomment-738536334
- [Webpack prerender-spa-plugin with compression-webpack-plugin. index.html not compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329040/webpack-prerender-spa-plugin-with-compression-webpack-plugin-index-html-not-com)

**CODE**

*vue.config.js*

```
const path = require('path')
const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
  /* ....shortened for brevity */

  // Compress option VI (with vue cli plugin, generator bug when invoked)
  // pluginOptions: {
  //   compression: {
  //     brotli: {
  //       filename: '[file].br[query]',
  //       algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
  //       include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
  //       minRatio: 0.8,
  //     },
  //     gzip: {
  //       filename: '[file].gz[query]',
  //       algorithm: 'gzip',
  //       include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
  //       minRatio: 0.8
  //     }
  //   }
  // },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .resolve.alias
        .set('@', resolve('src'))

    config
      .plugins.delete('prefetch') 
        
    config
      .optimization.splitChunks()

    config
      .output
      .chunkFilename('[id].js')

    // The below configurations are recommeneded only in prod.
    // config.when(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', config => { config... })

    // Compress option VII
    // config
      // .plugin('gzip')
      // .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin, [{
      //   algorithm: 'gzip',
      //   test: new RegExp('\\.(' + ['js', 'css'].join('|') + ')$'),
      //   threshold: 8192, // Assets larger than 8192 bytes are not processed
      //   minRatio: 0.8, // Assets compressing worse that this ratio are not processed
      // }])

    // Compress option VIII
    // config
      // .plugin('CompressionPlugin')
      // .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin)

    config
      .plugin('brotliCompress')
      .use(CompressionWebpackPlugin, [{
        exclude: /.map$/,
        // deleteOriginalAssets: true,
        cache: true,
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8,
      }])
  },
}
```

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.15.0",
    "audio-recorder-polyfill": "^0.4.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-compression": "~1.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
```

I appreciate all input. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the `compression-webpack-plugin` only compresses files, but it doesn't automatically configure the dev server to serve the compressed files in place of the original file.

However, you can manually setup a middleware via `vue.config.js`'s [`devServer` option](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) (passed through to [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver)) to do this:

1. Rewrite all `.js` requests that accept `br` encoding to append `.br` to the original URL, which matches the [`filename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin#filename) setting given to `compression-webpack-plugin`. This effectively fetches the `.br` file compressed by the plugin.
2. Set response headers to indicate the `br` [content encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) and `application/javascript` [content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) so that browsers could understand how to process the file.

#### Vue CLI 5 (Webpack 5)

Use [`devServer.setupMiddlewares`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetupmiddlewares):

```js
// vue.config.js
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CompressionPlugin({   1️⃣
        filename: '[path][base].br',
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        test: /\.js$/,
      })
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    setupMiddlewares(middlewares, devServer) {
      if (!devServer) {
        throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined')
      }

      middlewares.unshift({
        name: 'serve-brotli-js',
        path: '*.js',
        middleware: (req, res, next) => {
          if (req.get('Accept-Encoding')?.includes('br')) {
            1️⃣
            req.url += '.br'

            2️⃣
            res.set('Content-Encoding', 'br')
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8')
          }
          next()
        }
      })

      return middlewares
    }
  }
}
```

#### Vue CLI 4 (Webpack 4)

Use [`devServer.before`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore):

*Note: The only difference from Webpack 5 is the Express `app` is directly passed as the argument to `devserver.before()`.*

```js
// vue.config.js
⋮
module.exports = {
  ⋮
  devServer: {
    before(app) {
      // same code as Webpack 5 above
    }
  }
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-cli-serve-br-compressed-js)

Comment: Undoubtedly the response I was looking for, thanks Tony. I will be referencing the code sample with docs shared to add on to my knowledge of webpack. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which server is serving up these assets. If it's Express, looking at the screenshot with the header `X-Powered-By`, https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/71 shows that Brotli support hasn't been added to Express yet.

There might be a way to just specify the header for `content-encoding` manually though.

Comment: Your response taught me something @wegry, after further research on how webpack serves up an app, I found that it indeed uses express. 
  
Unfortunately, the issue still remains even after using approach #2 (use of gzip algo) and why it doesn't accomplish the end goal.
  
Could you add more context on what you mean by manually specifying the header for content encoding and how that triggers the compression? I value your response.

Comment: @DanderMensch tony19's response goes into further detail about how the server communicates with the browser to handle brotli encoding. The main point being that the server will have to determine content encoding in production vue builds.

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your nginx.conf file,If the client supports gzip Parsing , So as long as the server can return gzip Can be enabled gzip

```sh
gzip on; #  Turn on Gzip
gzip_static on; #  Turn on static file compression 
gzip_min_length  1k; #  Incompressible critical value , Greater than 1K It s only a matter of time 
gzip_buffers     4 16k;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_types     application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-httpd-php text/plain text/javascript text/css image/jpeg image/gif image/png; #  The type of file to be compressed 
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```